# at another boundary, one separating the territory of the test subject from another neighbor

Tags: meaning, sentence

> Emma Brindley has investigated the responses of European robins to the songs of neighbors and strangers. Despite the large and complex song repertoire of European robins, they were able to discriminate between the songs of neighbors and strangers. When they heard a tape recording of a stranger, they began to sing sooner, sang more songs, and overlapped their songs with the playback more often than they did on hearing a neighbor’s song. As Brindley suggests, the overlapping of song may be an aggressive response.
>
> However, this difference in responding to neighbor versus stranger occurred only when the neighbor’s song was played by a loudspeaker placed at the boundary between that neighbor’s territory and the territory of the bird being tested. If the same neighbor’s song was played at another boundary, one separating the territory of the test subject from another neighbor, it was treated as the call of a stranger. Not only does this result demonstrate that the robins associate locality with familiar songs,
>
> but it also shows that the choice of songs used in playback experiments is highly important.

---

Q 1. Where is "at another boundary, one separating the territory of the test subject from another neighbor " ?

Q 2. Where can I find the clue in the text above about " it also shows that the choice of songs used in playback experiments is highly important" ?

Comment: It seems the robin is saying "What did you do to my neighbor?" not "You're a stranger".

Answer (score 1):

Robin A has two neighbours, B on the left and C on the right. If the experimenters play B's song from A's left, he recognises it as B, but if they play the same song from the direction of C's territory, A treats it as a stranger's voice.

So, you can't use just any recording of a robin's song when making experiments; it has to be carefully chosen.